# format .csv file into new rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

I have a .csv file that has (45211rows, 1columns).
but i need to create new .scv file with (45211rows, 17columns)

**These are the column names**
age;"job";"marital";"education";"default";"balance";"housing";"loan";"contact";"day";"month";"duration";"campaign";"pdays";"previous";"poutcome";"y"

**I add a screenshot of the .csv file that I already have.**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas, the `read_csv` method has an option for setting the separator, which is `,` by default. To override, you can:

```py
pandas.read_csv(<PATH_TO_CSV_FILE>, sep=';', header=0)
```

This will return a new dataframe with the correct format. The `header=0` might not be needed, but it will force the returned dataframe to read the first line of the CSV file as column headers

Comment: Thank you, Ehab Ibrahim. This is the exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the CSV in Excel
2. Select all the data
3. Choose the Data tab atop the ribbon.
4. Select Text to Columns.
5. Ensure Delimited is selected and click Next.
6. Clear each box in the Delimiters section and instead choose Semi Colon.
7. Click Finish.